# ASP.NET application hangs after a call

Tags: asp.net, windows-vista

I'm having a simple ASP.NET application hosted on my local IIS6, under Vista.

It contains a button that when I click I execute a piece of code for recognizing the text in a WAV file (using the System.Speach.Recognition.SpeechRecognition class) and display the text in a label.

The code works great on a desktop application, and it almost works on the web one... I say almost, because if I debug, I can see that the recognizer returns the correct text from the WAV, I can see that I am finishing the handler for the button click with no error, but nothing gets displayed in my page, and the page appears like loading... it's hanging, or something... No errors, no timeout, nothing. Just loading...

I don't know if this detail helps, but in order to make the piece of code that was already working on the desktop application work on the web application, I had to set the identity of the ApplicationPool of my application to LocalSystem (security breach, I know). Otherwise, I would have received a Access Denied error (0x80070005(E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Do you have any ideea why the call hangs like that? I'm fighting with this for more than two days, time pressures me, and I have no clue... Any help is really welcomed!

Thanks!

Comment: you should make another user on the web server, give it asp.net security settings, then impersonate in your web.config.  see if that helps?

do you see anything in the event viewer on the server when the app hangs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After another one week of stuglles, I found an overcome to the problem. I'm posting this just so other that might have this problem find the solution faster.

The solution was to call the method for making the speech recognition on a different thread. I think this forced the release of all resources in that thread after the recognition ended.

I cannot make any sense why this even happened on the first place (I used using blocks and I closed and disposed all the object in all the imagining ways), but I suspected to be a memory release problem...

Anyway, a very simple call on another thread fix it!